# Сортировка работает по одному значению

Tags: javascript, json

Не получается отсортировать полученный список по 2ум полям: NAME и LASTNAME.

Сортировка идет только по *NAME*.

Как можно поправить ситуацию?

Спасибо.

```
// Сортировка значений 
response.features.sort(function (a, b) {
    if (a.attributes["NAME"] && b.attributes["NAME"]) {
        return (a.attributes["NAME"] > b.attributes["NAME"]) ? 1 : -1;
    }
    else if (a.attributes["NAME"]) {
        return -1;
    }
    else if (b.attributes["NAME"]) {
        return 1;
    }

    return (a.attributes["LASTNAME"] > b.attributes["LASTNAME"]) ? 1 : -1;
});
```

Comment: нужно определиться с тем как именно хочется соритровать

Comment: сначала по NAME, потом по LASTNAME

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по всему у вас всё попадает в первое условие:

```
return (a.attributes["NAME"] > b.attributes["NAME"]) ? 1 : -1;
```

в котором не учитывается сортировка по LASTNAME. Но это легко поправить:

```
if (a.attributes["NAME"] && b.attributes["NAME"]) {
    if (a.attributes["NAME"] == b.attributes["NAME") {
        return (a.attributes["LASTNAME"] > b.attributes["LASTNAME"]) ? 1 : -1;
    }
    return (a.attributes["NAME"] > b.attributes["NAME"]) ? 1 : -1;
}
```